# How to add switch in recycler view adapter android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have added switch in recycler view adapter layout,and written code inside recycler view adapter,and its working fine ,but the problem is
when i refresh the page or coming back to the page from other page the switch status of all the items present in recycler view becomes ON automatically,though i ON the switch for only One item .
So my question is though i ON the switch for one item ,and coming back again to the same page why all the recycler view items becomes ON..How to solve this problem.

Comment: post your code, Java logic, and XML as well.

Comment: save the switch status and position in sharedprefrence and when u comeback on that view then reset view data from shraredprefrence data

Comment: Please use data binding concept for this type of issue.And other solution is   to set tag to your switch in your adapter class for scrolling issue.

Comment: Check adapter getting new list or values to set the recyclerview. You can save the value of last ON/OFF in shared preferences or use same data for the refresh of recyclerview using adapter.

Comment: Can u post the code ,how will i save the switch status and position in  shared preferences and how to reset view data from shraredprefrence data .